Delete list of prefined blobs asynchronously from Azure
I have a file with multiple blobs that exist in a container.
I can delete them one by one by calling in a loop:
az storage blob delete

For me that solution would be fine if there is a way just to send the request and not having to wait if it's successful or not.
Now it takes forever to complete.
Is there a solution to have a deleteAsync or any other more performant solution to delete lists of blobs?


Is there a solution to have a deleteAsync or any other more performant solution to delete lists of blobs?

I agree with wenbo's point but,there is a more efficient way to delete multiple blobs without waiting for each operation to complete.
You can use az storage remove command with --recursive option is a recommended method by Microsoft for deleting all blobs in a container. This approach is generally more efficient for bulk deletions because it processes the removal more effectively than deleting each blob individually.
Command:
az storage remove --container-name $container --account-name $acc --account-key $accKey --recursive

Output:
storageAccountName="venkat7891"
storageAccountkey="xxxxx"
containerName="test"
az storage remove --account-name $storageAccountName --container-name $containerName --account-key $storageAccountkey --recursive
Azcopy command: ['azcopy', 'remove', 'https://venkat7891.blob.core.windows.net/test/?se=2024-08-13T07%3A52%3A01Z&sp=rdl&sv=20xxx-28&ss=b&srt=co&sig=', '--recursive', '--from-to=BlobTrash']
INFO: azcopy 10.24.0: A newer version 10.26.0 is available to download

INFO: Any empty folders will be processed, because source and destination both support folders

Job 467de99xxxx-2c9a18021484 has started
Log file is located at: /home/xxn/.azcopy/467dexxxxxxeb4c-63dd-2c9a18021484.log

100.0 %, 5 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 5 Total, 


Job 467dexxxx18021484 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0335
Number of File Transfers: 5
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Number of Symlink Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 5
Number of File Transfers Completed: 5
Number of Folder Transfers Completed: 0
Number of File Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Failed: 0
Number of File Transfers Skipped: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Skipped: 0
Total Number of Bytes Transferred: 35642
Final Job Status: Completed

Reference:

az storage | Microsoft Learn
blobstore - How to clean an Azure storage Blob container? - Stack Overflow by Abhinaba Chakraborty.


The issue here is that I don't want to delete all blobs in a container. Only a predefined list of them...

Then @CarlosAlvesJorge You can use the az storage blob delete-batch to delete the blob like your scenario https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch

If you want to delete the set of files like .py you can use --pattern*.py"` in your command to delete the them.

Is the above command worked for your expectation?

Not really because there is no pattern. Is just a list of thousands of jpgs. My solution is to use an Azure Function that deletes a particular blob. I just populate a queue with all of the blobs and let the azure function do its job

Then that is the possible answer, either you need to list with jpg files and deletes them.

I have just check az storage blob delete command not support --no-wait which help avoid waiting long-running to finish, also same as the features in az powershell -AsJob, samples:
az powershell:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -TemplateObject "xxx" -TemplateParameterFile "xxx" -AsJob
az cli:
az group deployment create -g 'xx' --template-uri 'xx' --parameters 'xx' --no-wait
I'm not familiar with bash syntax, but if you can use powershell, it's not hard to do it here, we can leverage start-job to manually run command as jobs to avoid waiting.
$storageAccountName = 'xxx'
$containerName = 'test'

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount

Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx | Remove-AzStorageBlob }


Thanks for the reply. I triedthis before... But, since to make it async I didn't wait for the job to complete and to close it basically it would crash the machine after around 2000 requests...

haha, it is sad.  You are getting too many blobs, so too many jobs in the background...
